# Advanced syntax

Tags: powershell, syntax

I came across the following line of syntax which is rather advanced (to me):

```
(Get-ADReplicationSubnet -Filter *) -notmatch [String]::Join('|',$c.Subnet)
```

The above does exactly what I want, retrieve the list of subnets that are not matched against the `$c.Subnet` variable. I tried recreating the same effect with the line below. This does not work.

```
Get-ADReplicationSubnet -Filter * | Where {$_.Name -notmatch $c.Subnet}
```

My question is; Can someone explain in simple English how the first line works? (Not sure on the `[String]::Join('|',$c.Subnet)` part. It is difficult to search for something you don't know the name of. Besides that, why does my version not work?

I should clarify that `$c.Subnet` is an array of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[String]::Join('|',$c.Subnet)` is call to the .NET framework -- the `Join()` method of the `String` class. You can take a look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx).

The documentation leads to the following explanation of the return value: `A string that consists of the elements in value delimited by the separator string. If value is an empty array, the method returns String.Empty.`

This means your return string will be something like `value1|value2|value3` (where each `value` is value from `$c.Subnet`), which `-notmatch` interprets as a regex, with `|` meaning `or`. What the first line does is return values that **do not match** `value1` **or** `value2` **or** `value3`.

Why (I think) your line doesn't work is because you're using `-notmatch` with an array rather than a string. [This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/18/speed-up-array-comparisons-in-powershell-with-a-runtime-regex.aspx) article has some usage info about the two.

Comment: So that technically means I could use any delimiting character instead of the |? The documentation link states that it uses the "specified seperator". The last thing I don't understand; Why does [String]:: get a notation with two colons?

Comment: @SiemHermans No you can't use any separator, the `|` is specific to regex syntax meaning match any of these.

Comment: @SiemHermans You "could" use any delimiting character you want with that method, but then `-notmatch` won't work because `|` has a special meaning in Powershell regex syntax (only `|` means **or** to `-notmatch`). `[String]::` is just the notation used when calling a **.NET class**. `[Math]::Pow(2, 2)` calls the `Pow()` method of the `Math` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
[String]::Join('|',$c.Subnet)
```

The [String] part means the .NET class.

The ::Join part means make a call to a static method of the String class, i.e. you don't have to "new up" an object before you use it.

The Join method takes and array and turns it into a string delineated by the pipe (in this case)

Someone else will have an explanation for the rest.